# PHP Laravel foreach

Tags: php, foreach, laravel-5

I want to make a user wall where all of his post will be loaded with those who has given comment under it. So I have defined following relations in my User model.

```
public function post()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Post::class);
}
public function comment()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

My Post model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
public function post_comment()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);
}
```

My Comment model:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}
public function post()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Post::class);
}
```

In my Controller:

```
public function wall($id)
{ 
  $all_post = Post::where('user_id',$id)->get();
  return view('client.wall',['all_post'=> $all_post]);
}
```

in my Blade file:

```
@foreach($all_post as $post)
Post Title: {{ $post->title }} //gets the title properly 
@foreach($post->post_comment as $comment) //this foreach loop throwing erros
Name: {{ $comment->user->name }}
Comment: {{ $comment->description }}
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Probably my logic is wrong to load the comments from database. Because I am getting errors.

Comment: Can you add the errors you are getting to your question?

Comment: Ki build korteso tawsif bhai? XD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this ad share if you still have an error

**Controller**

```
public function wall($id)
{ 
  $all_post = Post::where('user_id',$id)->with('post_comment')->get();
  return view('client.wall')->with('all_post',$all_post);
}
```

**VIEW**

```
@foreach($all_post as $post)
Post Title: {{ $post->title }} //gets the title properly 
  @foreach($post->post_comment as $comment) 
    Name: {{ $comment->user->name }}
    Comment: {{ $comment->description }}
  @endforeach
@endforeach
```